# Foreach with continue -- unexpected behavior

Tags: c#

I'm trying to iterate over a atring to count the number of occurrences of a certain types of characters.

However, I'm not sure what the problem with my logic is.

```
foreach (var character in stringToCount)
{
    if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(character))
    {
        alphaNumericCount++;
        continue;
    }

    if (char.IsLower(character))
    {
        lowercaseCount++;
        continue;
    }

    if (char.IsUpper(character))
    {
        uppercaseCount++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Only the `alphaNumericCount` variable is being incremented, and any lowercase or uppercase character is being ignored. I think I've misunderstood the use of the `continue` keyword.

If I comment out the first `if` statement then somehow the lowercase and uppercase checks work.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: Thank you everyone for your replies, they are all very good and informative. If I could award multiple correct answers I would!**

Comment: If a character is upper or lowercase, it is still a letter, is it not? :) Take the `continue` out of the first if statement.

Comment: just get rid of the `continue`s.  you don't need them

Comment: **Step through the code in the debugger** -- that is what it is for. Your mistake will become obvious after about five seconds of doing so.

Answer (score 6):

The `continue` keyword jumps to the next letter in the string (the next foreach iteration).  If you pass a lower case letter, it will increment in the first if statement, then move on to the next letter.

In your case, just remove the `continue` statements completely, and it will likely work as you expect.

Answer (score 5):

`continue` breaks out of the foreach loop for the given item. Since any letter is alphanumeric, it hits the first continue and "jumps" out, never giving the other statements a chance to run.

In your case, it sounds like you should remove all instances of that keyword. In general, "jumping" out of loops like that should be done with caution, as it can cause bugs like this.

Note: `break` can be used in `for` and `while` loops to do the same thing, and comes with the same caution.

Comment: `breaks` might not be the best word to use, since `break` is an entirely separate command.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Thats how I would say it when talking to another programmer. That said, I changed it to try and avoid confusion. Thanks for the comment! Incidentally, `break` has almost the exact same behavior as `continue` (although it exits the loop entirely)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `else if`:

```
foreach (var character in stringToCount)
{
    if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(character))
    {
        alphaNumericCount++;

        if (char.IsLower(character))
            lowercaseCount++;

        else if (char.IsUpper(character))
            uppercaseCount++;
    }
}
```

Because `Continue` skips the remaining code of the current iteration and jumps to the next iteration.

Comment: This will cause the same problem as the original.  `'a'` will not increment `lowercaseCount` :)

Comment: `else if` is preferred to `continue` when you *want* this behavior though, as it doesn't disrupt the execution flow. Not right for this situation, but good advice in general!

Comment: No real need to use `else` here. A letter can't be both upper and lower case.

Comment: @ColinDeClue But the condition will be checked

Comment: @ColinDeClue True, but it would provide a micro-optimization, as the else would short circuit before actually calling the "ToUpper" function. This would be more important on a more complicated check.

Comment: No point in worrying about micro-optimizations before you've profiled and discovered an actual problem. I'd say that `else` is in fact worse for readability, because it implies that both the `if` and the `else` conditions can be true at the same time, and you want to protect against that.

Comment: @ColinDeClue agree on unecesarily micro-optimizing; it wouldn't likely be an issue here. As far as readability, I would tend to disagree, though its purely a matter of opinion and style, there isn't a "right" answer.

Answer (score 2):

> **continue** (C# Reference)
>
> The continue statement passes control to the ***next***
>   iteration of the enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement in
>   which it appears.

From within a loop, you have two keywords that affect the flow of control:

1. break - Is like a goto END
2. continue - Is like a goto NEXT

In C#, the foreach() loop on an IEnumerable (or any object that provides a GetEnumerator() method with a proper enumerator object is implemented by first getting the enumerator object for the collection, visiting each item in the collection (enumerator) with enumerator.MoveNext(), and accessing that current item with enumerator.Current;

As a mental exercise, if you did not have foreach() or any other looping construct, you could implement it with ***goto*** and labels.

```
foreach(var item in container) // translates to lines 1 - 4 below
{
    if(foo) continue;          // line 5
    if(bar) break;             // line 6
    // do something
}
```

translates to

```
 1:       var enumerator = container.GetEnumerator();  // initialize the enumerator
 2: next: if(enumerator.MoveNext()) 
 3:       {
 4:          var item = enumerator.Current;  // get item to work on (the "topic")
 5:          if(foo) goto next;              // 'continue' keyword - skips to next
 6:          if(bar) goto end;               // 'break' keyword - exits loop
 7:          // do something
 8:          goto next;                      // normal loop iteration to next item
 9:       }    
10: end:                                     // loop done
```

As per the question, if you want to hit multiple conditions in the same loop, don't use continue at all; continue will skip everything after it for the current iteration. Use separate independent conditions so they all have the chance to execute.

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the most readable method in my opinion:

```
int alphaNumericCount = stringToCount.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
int lowercaseCount = stringToCount.Count(char.IsLower);
int uppercaseCount = stringtoCount.Count(char.IsUpper);
```

If you can't stand to repeat the iterations then:

```
foreach(var c in stringToCount.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit))
{
    ++alphaNumericCount;
    if (char.IsLower(c)) ++lowercaseCount;
    if (char.IsUpper(c)) ++uppercaseCount;
}
```